# disabling events in hightcharts js

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need to disable the events on the legends in an high charts stacked area chart. Here is my code:

```
chart: {
      type: 'area',
    },
    point: {
      events: {
        legendItemClick: function () {
          return false; // <== returning false will cancel the default action
        },
      },
    },
    title: {
      text: title,
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      min: startDateInMS,
      max: endDateInMS,
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: yLabel,
      },
    },
    series: data,
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'normal',
      },
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false,
    },
  };
```

It seems ok according to the documentation but you can still click in the legend to remove items from the chart which I don't want. Any help would be lovely!!

Comment: Figured out the issue was with how you are nesting your event

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is coming from the fact that you are assigning that click event to point, but from the looks of it your chart is an `area` and you are applying the click event to the wrong property.

You are putting it under `lines` meanwhile, it needs to be nested like - `plotOptions -> area -> events -> legendItemClick`

Instead, make sure your event is nested like this:

```
chart: {
      type: 'area',
    },
    plotOptions: {
      area: {
        events: {
          legendItemClick: function () {
            return false; // <== returning false will cancel the default action
          }
        }
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: title,
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      min: startDateInMS,
      max: endDateInMS,
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: yLabel,
      },
    },
    series: data,
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'normal',
      },
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false,
    },
};
```

Comment: i just tries that the code you provided and still nothing...arghhh!!

Comment: even when i try and console log out what is going on that function never fires

Comment: @Jorge can you post your full code / create a jsfiddle replicating the issue?

Answer (score -1):

got it...i had another plot option further downtime code that was over writing this code:

```
chart: {
      type: 'area',
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'normal',
      },
      area: {
        events: {
          legendItemClick: function () {
            return false; // <== returning false will cancel the default action
          },
        },
      },
    },
    title: {
      text: title,
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      min: startDateInMS,
      max: endDateInMS,
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: yLabel,
      },
    },
    series: data,
    credits: {
      enabled: false,
    },
  };
```

thanks for your help!!